# Strings with parameters for a method in C#

Tags: c#, string

My sentence is: `!doar 12345, rayantt`

Using string.Contains(!doar), I need get the other values as:

```
int mount = 12345;
string destiny = "rayannt";
```

Comment: Your question (which is actually a collection of statements) doesn't make any sense.  Please refine and provide more information.

Comment: could you please more clear about the requirements? and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Why did you need to do it. Get more information or any background, when you ask any guestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the `input` be the input string as you stated in the question, `searchString` be the string that you wanted to search for; `strParam` and `intParam` are the two required outputs; Now consider the following code:

```
string input = "!doar 12345, rayantt";
string searchString = "!doar";
string strParam=string.Empty ;
int intParam=0;
if (input.Contains(searchString)) // check for the existence of the search string in given string
   {
      input = input.Replace(searchString, ""); // remove the searchstring from the input
      string[] contents = input.Split(',');
      int.TryParse(contents[0], out intParam); // collect the integer param
      strParam=contents[1]; // collect the string param
   }
// here you get 12345 in intParam and "rayantt" in strParam
```